# Delete operation sets null to navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nullable-reference-types

This is the structure of my database:

1. One User can have many Categories
2. One Category can have many Tags.
3. One Tag can have many Transfer.
4. One User can have many Accounts.
5. One Account can have many transfers.

Following the EF Core guidelines on using nullable navigation properties, this is the code for the `Author` navigation property between the `Category` and `User` relationship.

```
private User? _author;
public User Author
{
    get => this._author ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(...); 
    set => this._author = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
}
```

However when I try to delete a `User`, EF Core invokes both the setter (setting value of `null`) and the getter of that navigation property. Which apparently will cause exceptions to be thrown.

All relations are required and have cascade behavior so I do not understand why null value should be set to that property...

Comment: Don't do validation in properties. Validate entity classes before saving them. I wonder which guidelines you refer to.

Comment: @GertArnold See this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#non-nullable-properties-and-initialization

Comment: That's only the getter.

Comment: @GertArnold, I know, but it does not matter - the getter is immediately called as well. I have described this in the question.

Comment: Yes, but you should allow EF to do that. I don't know why it does that (that requires a lot more visible code), but it seems necessary.

Comment: From the same link: *"Note that EF must be configured to always access the **backing field** and not the property, as it relies on being able to read the value even when unset; consult the documentation on backing fields on how to do this, and consider specifying `PropertyAccessMode.Field` to make sure the configuration is correct."*. Although this is the default for EFC 3.0+, and your example really works for me. Make sure in your real case you use backing field name recognized by EFC and you haven't disabled the usage of backing fields.